# Relationships between VS ans MSVC version

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

I can't make up a puzzle. I meet names like Visual C++15 (here for example: https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/). But other sources say that the last version to the moment is 14.31 (wikipedia stays with them: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Visual_C%2B%2B). It's also gets challenging for me at the moment to check out the version myself. So there are three questions:

- What is Visual C++15 (is it compiler version or something like language dialectic specification) and if it's not a compiler version, so what is it?
- Is there any relationship between VS version and version (or a model) of it's built-in C++ compiler?
- Which version of VS should I use to successfully use SFML?

Thanks!

Comment: The Wikipedia article you linked contains a table of MSVC version numbers for each Visual Studio version.

Comment: See https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/releasenotes/vs2017-relnotes-v15.0 and **Internal version numbering** on Wikipedia page you reference.

Comment: But I can't feel what's difference between MSVC and Visual c++ (and what is 15 if there is 14.31 the latest release with VS2022).

Comment: When the SFML page says "Visual C++", it actually means "Visual Studio". (The version numbering in the "Visual family" is a neverending cause for confusion and pain. For example, just look at "the cl.exe included in 14.22 (Visual Studio 2019 16.2.5) reports its version as 19.22.27905" on the Wikipedia page...)

Comment: @Gregor the VisualC++ ver 14.31 is the latest version of the compiler in the Visual Studio. The version 15 that you mention here is the version of Visual studio and not the compiler

Comment: This document describes that the mscv version in VS2015 to 2022 are binary compatible: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/porting/binary-compat-2015-2017?view=msvc-170)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. The Visual C++15, that you mention here, is in fact Visual Studio version 15(aka Visual Studio 2017). It isn't a compiler version but in fact a version of the IDE.
2. There is no relation with VS versions directly with C++ standards. But it's more like, some versions of C++ can only be supported on the latest VS versions. for e.g.. C++20 is only supported on Visual studio 2022. C++11/C++14/C++17 is supported in Visual studio 2019 and higher.
3. For SMFL, it just says any C++ compiler but I would honestly suggest Visual Studio 2017 or higher.

Comment: VS 2015 and higher means I can use VS 2022?

Comment: @Gregor yes, you can use VS2022. It does support all versions of C++ until C++20. Also, if this answers your query. Please mark the answer as right.